# Creating elements in javascript - just wondering

Tags: javascript, dom, element

I was writing some code and then faced up with that problem. Here is a part of my code, just creating a div, appending it and then funcion which may be able to delete it

```
var mainCont=document.createElement('div');
mainCont.innerHTML="<div style='display: block; height: 20px;'></div>";
mainCont.innerHTML=mainCont.innerHTML+"<div style='display: block; height: 40px; width: 100%; text-align: right;'></div>";

document.body.appendChild(mainCont);

var delete=function()
{
    document.body.removeChild(mainCont);
}
```

When i use delete function i got an error. But when i do this, then no errors appear:

```
someVariable=mainCont; 
var delete=function()
{
    document.body.removeChild(someVariable);
}
```

Why does the first code not work? And why the second does? I would like to know more about this problem but its hard to easilly find more "sophisticated" things like that in google. Thanks in advance for any sources and answers

Comment: Seems to work fine for me, as long as you rename your `delete` function to an allowed function name like `deleteMainCont` (`delete` is a reserved keyword in javascript)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be defining var mainCont in a separate scope from your delete function.

```
someVariable=mainCont;
```

Calling the above without var will put someVariable into the global scope which gives the delete function access to the variable. Try to make a jsFiddle for us if this is not the issue so we can debug it.